# Mean and Variance of Continuous Random Variable

Tags: variance, mean

I have a problem on my homework about the continuous random variable $y$ where the cdf is $F(y)=\frac{1}{(1+e^{-y})}$.

Part a is asking for the pdf which I found to be $\frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2}$.

Part b asks for the mean and variance of $y$ but when I tried to find the $E(y)$, I got zero with the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ of $\frac{ye^y}{(e^y+1)^2}$. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This distribution is the [standard logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution), and its moments and information are examined in [deCani and Stine (1986)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1986.10475398).  The distribution function can be written equivalently in either of the following two forms:

$$F_Y(y) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-y}} = \frac{e^y}{1+e^y} .$$

The density function can be written in either of the following two forms:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{e^{-y}}{(1+e^{-y})^2} = \frac{e^{y}}{(1+e^{y})^2}.$$

Since $f_Y(y) = f_Y(-y)$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the density is symmetric around zero, so it is trivial to show that $\mathbb{E}(Y)=0$.  Deriving the variance is more difficult, but it can be done by a number of different methods.  This simplest method is to derive the moment-generating function of the distribution and use this to get the variance.  Another method is to derive the variance is by direct application of the variance formula, using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) in conjunction with the symmetry of the density function.  (This leads to an integral involving the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), which then requires you to take limits of this function using an asymptotic form.  The mathematics for this derivation gets pretty long.)

Since this is homework, I will not show you how to do either of these derivations, but I might come back to this question later and add them, once enough time has elapsed so that your homework has been submitted.  I recommend attempting the derivation of the variance by first finding the moment-generating function.  If you have trouble you could consult the cited paper to review their method.

Comment: Thanks for name of distribution, which was eluding me. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:**

Setting what I take to be your CDF equal to $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ and solving for the quantile function (inverse CDF) in terms of $U,$  I simulate a sample of ten million
observations as shown below. [Thanks to @Noah for recent clarification of notation in Problem.]

Then, when I plot your PDF through the histogram of the large sample, that density function
seems to fit pretty well.

```
set.seed(1019)     # for reproducibility
u = runif(10^7);  x = -log(1/u - 1)
mean(x);  sd(x);  sqrt(pi^2/3);  2*sd(x)/sqrt(10^7)
[1] -0.000594651   # aprx E(X) = 0
[1] 1.81335        # aprx SD(X) = 1.813799
[1] 1.813799       # exact SD(X) per Wikipedia on 'logistic distn'   
[1] 0.003626701    # aprx 95% margin of simulation error for E(X)

hist(x, prob=T, br=100, col="skyblue2")
  curve(exp(x)/(exp(x)+1)^2, -10, 10, add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

I don't pretend that this is a 'worked answer' to your problem, but
I hope it may give you enough clues to improve the version of the problem you posted and to finish the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think you did something wrong?

\begin{align}
& \Pr(Y\le y) = F(y) = \frac 1 {1+e^{-y}} \\[10pt]
\text{and } & \Pr(Y\ge -y) = 1-F(-y) = 1- \frac 1 {1+e^y} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{e^y}{1+e^y} = \frac{e^y\cdot e^{-y}}{(1+e^y)\cdot e^{-y}} = \frac 1 {e^{-y}+1},
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
\Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(Y \ge -y).
$$
So this distribution is symmetric about $0.$

Therefore, if the expected value exists, it is $0.$

You can also show that the density function is an even function:
\begin{align}
f(y) & = \frac{e^y}{(1+e^y)^2}. \\[12pt]
f(-y) & = \frac{e^{-y}}{(1+e^{-y})^2} = \frac{e^{-y}\cdot\left( e^y \right)^2}{\Big((1+e^{-y}) \cdot e^y \Big)^2} = \frac{e^y}{(e^y+1)^2} = f(y).
\end{align}
Since the density is an even function, the expected value must be $0$ if it exists.

The expected value $\operatorname E(Y)$ exists if $\operatorname E(|Y|) < +\infty.$